# Is 'Iraq expecting U.S. troop withdrawal' a complete sentece?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have come across a news heading: As Iran prepares to bury Soleimani, Iraq expecting U.S. troop withdrawal.

From my English grammar knowledge, I think this is a complex sentence. The first clause is Iran prepares to bury Soleimani with conjunction word As. The second clause is Iraq expecting U.S. troop withdrawal. I don't think the second clause is a correct sentence, and it should be Iraq is expecting U.S. troop withdrawal. Because we need a 'is' to make it a continuous tense, and then complete the sentence.

The heading can't be wrong, because it comes from Washington Post. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It is *not* a complete sentence, and it is not *meant to be one!*

It's called ***headlinese*** where they take some liberty on grammar rules. This is because they have limited spaces on tabloids and dailies.

Further reading: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921

Comment: I agree. I’d add that it’s not just limited space that many say has driven the development and use of this specialised abbreviated variant of standard English. It’s also the need to splash a front page, etc with a cut down “sentence” that speeds up the processing of information by the reader. It can allow the reader to skim the page and get the main news, or find articles of interest, in seconds. Good headlines are also catchy and attractive (in an advertising sense) and invite the reader to find out more by reading the whole article.